# How do I work with certain groupings of newtypes

Tags: purescript

I'm trying to get the following to work, but I can't seem to get it right. I would expect something like this to work:

```
newtype Skill = Skill { name :: String, other :: Int }
newtype Feature = Feature { name :: String, something :: Boolean }
newtype Special = Special { name :: String, different :: String }

type Namable = forall r. { name :: String | r }

changeName :: forall m. String -> m Namable -> m Namable
changeName newName (ctor namable) = 
    ctor $ namable { name = newName }
```

The error looks something like:

```
Error 1 of 1
  Unable to parse module:
  unexpected "namable"
  expecting @, ::, operator or )
```

Basically I want to add functionality to a set of `newtype`s. This will not always be the entire set and not always more than one, but I'd like to write the actual functionality "ignorant" of the types I define. If in the future I decide to add a `newtype Statistic`, I want it to "just work".

To improve this question I was wondering if there is a name for the type of signature I'm looking for?

```
f :: forall m a. (a -> a) -> m a -> m a
```

Seems like a less generic [`Functor`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude/blob/master/src/Data/Functor.purs) definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what I needed was the `Newtype` typeclass:

```
newtype Skill = Skill { name :: String, other :: Int }
derive instance newtypeSkill :: Newtype Skill _
newtype Feature = Feature { name :: String, something :: Boolean }
derive instance newtypeFeature :: Newtype Feature _
newtype Special = Special { name :: String, different :: String }
derive instance newtypeSpecial :: Newtype Special _

type Namable = forall r. { name :: String | r }

changeModel ::forall p m. Newtype m p => (p -> p) -> m -> m
changeModel f m = over wrap f m

changeName :: forall m. Newtype m Namable => String -> m -> m
changeName newName m = changeModel (\x -> x { name = newName }) m

fishing :: Skill
fishing = Skill { name : "Fishing", other : 2 }

skating = changeName "Skating" fishing
```

The `changeModel` function is now entirely generic over `Newtype` types. `changeName` is now as simple as function application.

Details:

Because I'm using [`Newtype`](https://github.com/paf31/24-days-of-purescript-2016/blob/master/5.markdown) (also look at [this info](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-newtype/blob/master/src/Data/Newtype.purs) I get things like `over` and `wrap` for free.

The [`over`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-newtype/2.0.0/docs/Data.Newtype#v:over) function is a pain to understand because the examples are written in a point free style.

The [`wrap`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-newtype/2.0.0/docs/Data.Newtype#v:wrap) function returns the type constructor.

The lambda function is "what you want done to the data of your newtype".

The `m` at the end is the actual value you are passing in. This is the value which gets unwrapped and passed into your lambda.